# CSS parent, child, and grandson

Tags: css

I need to override the height of all the child of a parent except a child and his child's. how can i do that ?
I use the id of the parent and the not option #parent *:not(here i want to select a child which is a parent of another).
Please can anyone help me thanks a lot <3.

Comment: can you provide the html and css that you have written

Comment: sorry i cant because its too large but i can giv you a simple example

Comment: yes please give simple example

Comment: <div id="1">
 <div id="1.1">
  <div id="1.11"> </div>
 <div id="1.2">
 <div id="1.3>
 <div id="1.4">
  <div id="1.41"> </div>
  <div id="1.42"> </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
I need to override all except 1.4 and its child which are 1.41 and 1.42

Comment: wont it be easier to give those elements another class so that you can modify all of them at once?

Comment: i cant am using drupal at a specific module

Comment: sorry, there is nothing that can be done

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't have parent selectors, so there's no way to say `:not(any child which is itself a parent)` automatically unfortunately. I believe you'll have to apply a class to every child which is itself a parent. And then you'll need a second selector to catch the grandchild. So:

```
#parent > *:not(.haschildren),
#parent > *:not(.haschildren) > * {
}
```

Or just give the same class to every tag involved. But this is probably more typing overall than just using two selectors:

```
#parent *:not(.tagswewanttoignore) {
}
```